# Is MDAC supported in Sql Server 2011 ("Denali")?

Tags: sql-server, mdac

I have been told that next version of SQL Server (2011 - "Denali") won't use MDAC but a "vendor dll" as other RDBMS do. Is this true or MDAC will work anyway?

If this is true the zero installation I have for my client application (because MDAC is already installed I don't need to do anything but copy an exe in the client machine) will become a Sql Server dll + My exe deployment.

May you give some advice on this?

Comment: Who told you this? Any links corroborating this?

Comment: next = the one that will come after 2008 R2. I have been told from a friend who as me is a Delphi developer, I didn't ask him the source of the information.

Comment: @user193655: the next version of SQL Server will be SQL Server 2011 (code-named "Denali") - due out towards the end of 2011; updated your post accordingly

Comment: May be I am wrong and MDAC will be supported and the dll will be an option, anyway if you have some info on this I would like to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDAC was, pretty well, the name for an installer that installed multiple different data access components, such as the OLEDB provider and the ODBC driver. The last recognisable version of MDAC (2.8) dates from the Windows Server 2003 era.

The more modern installer for such client components is the [SQL Server Native Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130892%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx). This includes updated OLEDB and ODBC components, with support for newer SQL Server features such as MARS. The older components will *probably* continue to work for some time, but as I say, you won't have access to some newer features.

I can find no specific references in the [Denali BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) to any deprecation of data access technologies (as opposed, say, to where it states that Itanium is no longer supported)

The BOL does include a guide on updating applications from [MDAC to Native Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131035%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)